How to add compute instructions to VersionedTransaction
I have a versionedTransaction, all i can get is the compiledInstructions. Is there a way in js by which i can decode these compiledInstructions and append my computeBudget instructions and finally make it a Versioned Transaction

I believe you search for TransactionMessage.decompile
const txMessage = TransactionMessage.decompile(transaction.message);
txMessage.instructions.push(instruction);

const messageV0 = txMessage.compileToV0Message();
const vTransaction = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
vTransaction.sign([...]);

const txId = await connection.sendTransaction(vTransaction);

Check some details

https://docs.jup.ag/docs/additional-topics/composing-with-versioned-transaction

